# Traceroute Vulnerability (CVE-2023-46316) fixes are not released

Tags: package-management, security

We are currently using ubuntu 20.04 LTS version in our environment, This traceroute CVE-2023-46316 vulnerability was reported for the Installed package : traceroute_1:2.1.0-2,
and this Vulnerability was fixed as part of ESM.

However, Ubuntu 20.04 does not reach EOL, So why was this particular package  released only as part of ESM?

Installed package : traceroute_1:2.1.0-2
Fixed package : traceroute_1:2.1.0-2ubuntu0.20.04.1~esm1

Comment: The package is in the Universe repo, and thus only patched upstream or as part of Ubuntu Pro. Also, see below.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a patched version `2.1.3` or `2.1.5` from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/traceroute/files/traceroute/traceroute-2.1.3/):

```
sudo apt remove traceroute
wget https://unlimited.dl.sourceforge.net/project/traceroute/traceroute/traceroute-2.1.3/traceroute-2.1.3.tar.gz
tar xvf traceroute-2.1.3.tar.gz
cd traceroute-2.1.3
make 
sudo make install
```

Check the version:

```
traceroute --version

Modern traceroute for Linux, version 2.1.3
Copyright (c) 2016  Dmitry Butskoy,   License: GPL v2 or any later
```